# Calling a method with an argument trough reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following code which allows me to input in the scanner the Employee getter method that I want to call and it will do it using reflection (the name of the method should not appear anywhere in the code). This works for getter methods but I now need to modify the code to do something similar for setter methods. I have been trying to figure how to do it for the past week but I have been unable. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee e = Employee.testEmployee();                // a sample employee
    Class cls = e.getClass();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);           // to parse data the user types in
    String nextCommand;

    // until the user enters "quit", get the next input from the user, and if it matches
    // a given command, get the desired information from the employee object
    do {
      System.out.print("Enter command >> ");
      nextCommand = scanner.next();
      Method method = null;
      try{
        method = cls.getMethod(nextCommand);
      }
      catch(NoSuchMethodException x) {
      }
      try{
        System.out.println(method.invoke(e));
      }
      catch(IllegalAccessException x) {
      }
      catch(java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException x) {
      }
      catch(NullPointerException x) {
      }
    } while (! nextCommand.equals("quit"));
  }
```

Comment: Read the javadoc for `getMethod()`. You can pass other arguments to it.

Comment: I know, but the thing is that I need to get the method only by using the header name, not the input parameters...

Comment: You don't have a choice in this case. If you don't know the parameters, how are you going to invoke it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a code sample that does what you want to achieve:

```
public class Test {
    private static HashSet<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();

    static {
        classes.add(String.class);
        classes.add(Integer.class);
        classes.add(GregorianCalendar.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException,
            SecurityException, IllegalAccessException,
            IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        X obj = new X();
        obj.setField("lala");
        Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod("getField", null);
        System.out.println(method.invoke(obj, null));

        Method setMethod = getWorkingMethod(obj);
        setMethod.invoke(obj, "who let the dogs out");
        System.out.println(obj.getField());
    }

    private static Method getWorkingMethod(Object obj) {
        Method method = null;
        for (Class<?> c : classes) {
            try {
                method = obj.getClass().getMethod("setField", c);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
                continue;
            }
            if(method != null){
                return method;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such method found!");
    }
}

class X {
    private String stringField;

    public void setField(String s) {
        stringField = s;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return stringField;
    }
}
```

Output:

> lala
>   who let the dogs out

Notes:

- Create a collection (I used a `HashSet`) that stores `Class<?>` objects. You will use these to iterate over the possibilities and see if a method with that argument exists.
- Use a try-catch to see if the method exists (an exception is thrown when it can't find it).
- This will not work for overloaded methods. If this is your scenario, you'll have to make adjustments. I expect it to be no problem though, since you said this was meant for setters (which typically don't have overloads).

Comment: But to get the method if it is a setter I need the input parameters, which I don't have, I believe.

Comment: @user2848190: obviously you'll need to provide a value if you want to set a value.. You'll have to ask input from your user to call your setter with the input he provides.

Comment: Yes I guess so.  But if I do that how do I know if the setter method he has called actually exists before asking for the value?

Comment: @user2848190: add a check `if(method != null)` before asking for more a value.

Comment: But without asking for the value I cannot find if the setter method exists using getMethod...

Comment: @user2848190: Sorry, I misunderstood you! Yes, you will have to find a way to get the datatype of the parameter indeed. You could hold a list of `Class<?>` objects in a collection and loop trough them until you find a method that exists.

Comment: @user2848190: updated my post to showcase something that does close to what you want (if you don't use overloads).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Got it working a different way (using getMethods and searching the array returned), but the little discussion we had here helped me quite a lot, so I am marking this as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid calling the `getter` and `setter` methods by directly accessing the `Field` through reflection.

The [Field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) object has various `get` and `set` methods that can be used to manipulate field values.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField%28java.lang.String%29

**EXAMPLE**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;


public class MyObject {

    private String fieldA;


    public String getFieldA() {
        return fieldA;
    }


    public void setFieldA(String fieldA) {
        this.fieldA = fieldA;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        myObject.setFieldA("Test");

        Class clazz = myObject.getClass();

        Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("fieldA");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        String fieldA = (String) field.get(myObject);
        System.out.println(fieldA);

        field.set(myObject, "Test2");
        fieldA = (String) field.get(myObject);

        System.out.println(fieldA);
        field.setAccessible(false); //be sure to return field to private
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt accessing a field directly is something you want to do. Setters are exactly there to provide validation logic (encapsulation), bypassing this violates OOP. Reflection in terms of OOP is already questionable, but this is another level.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel You make a very valid point.  I usually validate outside of the entity.  The value would have been cleaned prior to calling the set method.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution (method or field resolution) in java slows down you execution time by 'orders of 10 or 100', hence not a smart design decision. So, resolve once at start time, cache method instance, and execute it from cache. Avoid frequent lookups using reflection.